# accessing element in an array -python

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following code

```
a = [filled with something] //some list that is filled
for element in a:
    if element is 5:
        return "YES"
return "NO"
```

This does not always work with test cases, but if i replace the if statement to 'if a[element] is 5' it works perfectly, but why?

Comment: Instead of for loop use the 'in' operator.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if an array contains 5 use:

```
if 5 in a:
  return "YES"
```